# Python - Use RegEx on HTML file for specific word?

Tags: python, html, regex, email, beautifulsoup

I have emails that have embedded HTML tables in them. I use `BeautifulSoup` to extract the data tables, but there is data just outside the tables that I can't capture with this method.

Here is an example email with two data tables:

[image]

Like I said, I use `bs4` to capture the information from inside the tables' cells. I then turn this data into a DataFrame. I would like to also capture the `Package` price in order to append it to each Fish-Weight value. Simple commands like:

```
for line in f: 
    if ("Package" in line):
    print("line:", line)
```

...fail to print anything. When I examine the HTML closer I see that it looks like this:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FW: NEFS 11 fish available</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><b>Subject: </b>FW: NEFS 11 fish available</td></tr><tr><td><b>From: </b>Claire Fitz-Gerald <claire@capecodfishermen.org></td></tr><tr><td><b>Date: </b>6/2/2016 5:55 PM</td></tr></table><br>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; ">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi";
    panose-1:2 11 7 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book";
    panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Verdana;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#0563C1;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#954F72;
    text-decoration:underline;}
p.msonormal0, li.msonormal0, div.msonormal0
    {mso-style-name:msonormal;
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0in;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0in;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
span.EmailStyle18
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">Please see below quota listings.<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">Thanks,<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Book&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D">Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><i><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Book&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Demi&quot;,sans-serif;color:#002776">Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Book&quot;,sans-serif;color:#DE3500">~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#DE3500"><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Demi&quot;,sans-serif;color:#002776">Celebrating 25 years. Navigating 25 more.</span></b><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Franklin Gothic Book&quot;,sans-serif;color:#002060">
<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:#1F497D"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">From:</span></b><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"> NEFS V [mailto:nefsector5@gmail.com]
<br>
<b>Sent:</b> Thursday, June 02, 2016 12:32 PM<br>
<b>To:</b> Ben Martens &lt;ben@mainecoastfishermen.org&gt;; Claire Fitz-Gerald &lt;claire@capecodfishermen.org&gt;; Dave Leveille 2 &amp; 6 &lt;nefs02@gmail.com&gt;; Hank SHS &lt;shsector@gmail.com&gt;; John Haran 10 &amp; 13 &lt;sector13@comcast.net&gt;; Linda MaCann 7 &amp; 8 &lt;nbsector07@comcast.net&gt;;
 mike walsh 6 &lt;fisherwoman2042003@yahoo.com&gt;; Patrick NCCS &lt;patrick@penobscoteast.org&gt;; paula lynch 12 &lt;paulasectorx@yahoo.com&gt;; Spice Montgomery 3 &lt;nefsiii@gmail.com&gt;; Stephanie Rafael-DeMello 9 &lt;nbsector9@gmail.com&gt;; tory bramante 6 &lt;torybra@aol.com&gt;; NEFS
 11 Charles Felch &lt;boat1151@aol.com&gt;; NEFS 11 David Goethel &lt;egoethel@comcast.net&gt;; NEFS 11 Fanel Dobre &lt;stormdancer4@yahoo.com&gt;; NEFS 11 Geordie King &lt;kinggeordie@comcast.net&gt;; NEFS 11 Jamie Hayward &lt;jamienjolyn@comcast.net&gt;; NEFS 11 Jayson Driscoll &lt;jaysondriscoll@yahoo.com&gt;;
 NEFS 11 Mike and Pat Anderson &lt;padi.anderson@gmail.com&gt;; NEFS 11 Neil Pike &lt;sandipike@hotmail.com&gt;; NEFS 11 Richard Anderson &lt;monkfishing@hotmail.com&gt;; NEFS 11 Tom Lyons &lt;tomrlyons@hotmail.com&gt;; Puggy &lt;charles.felch@yahoo.com&gt;<br>
<b>Subject:</b> NEFS 11 fish available<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">All,<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">NEFS 11 has the following available:<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><u><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Package 1:&nbsp; $ 500.00</span></u></b><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
<div>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="396" style="width:297.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td width="232" style="width:174.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gb cod east</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td width="55" style="width:41.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td width="109" style="width:82.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">1</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gb cod west</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">5</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gom cod</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">148</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gb haddock east</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">1</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gb haddock west</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">2</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gom haddock</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">12</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">white hake</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">4</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">pollock</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">162</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">redfish</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">25</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">​</span><b><u><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Package 2: $ 5,225.00</span></u></b><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
<div>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="387" style="width:290.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td width="232" style="width:174.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gom cod</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td width="45" style="width:34.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td width="109" style="width:82.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">916</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gom winter fl</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">498</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;display:none"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="387" style="width:290.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td width="232" style="width:174.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gom haddock</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td width="45" style="width:34.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td width="109" style="width:82.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">284</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">white hake</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">505</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">dab</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">1,293</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">pollock</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">812</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">redfish</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">1,910</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">witch fl</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">352</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">cc/gom yellowtail</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">306</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">​<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><u><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Package 3:&nbsp; $ 44,150.00</span></u></b><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
<div>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="449" style="width:337.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td width="232" style="width:174.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gb cod east</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td width="45" style="width:34.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td width="63" style="width:47.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td width="109" style="width:82.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">5</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gb cod west</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">17</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gom cod</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">5,000</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gom winter fl</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">2,900</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="449" style="width:337.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td width="232" style="width:174.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gb haddock east</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td width="45" style="width:34.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td width="63" style="width:47.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td width="109" style="width:82.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">836</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gb haddock west</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">2,118</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">gom haddock</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">18,000</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">white hake</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">8,842</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">dab</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">8,650</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">pollock</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">78,000</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">redfish</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">35,923</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">witch fl</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">3,250</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">cc/gom yellowtail</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt"></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">2,250</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><u><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Package 4:&nbsp; $ 43,135.00</span></u></b><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif">GOM cod&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;6,900</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif">dabs&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 3,800</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif">witch fl&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 4,000</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif">cc/gom yt&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 5,100</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">GB West Cod&nbsp; - 3,251 lbs libe weight = $ 6,500.00</span></b><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><br clear="all">
<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><br>
-- <o:p></o:p></p>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal">Daniel Salerno<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal">NEFS 5 &amp; NEFS 11<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal">401-932-0070<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="MsoNormal">401-633-6539 (fax)<o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not an expert with HTML, is there a way to capture and append the `Package` price to its corresponding Fish-Weight values?

My relevant code is:

```
package_regex = re.compile(r'package(.*)(?=\n)', re.IGNORECASE)
with open(file_path) as in_f:
    for line in in_f:
        for match in package_regex.finditer(in_f.read()):
            price, stuff = match.groups()
            print("price:", price)
            print("stuff:", stuff)



with open(file_path) as in_f:
    msg = email.message_from_file(in_f)             #type: <class 'email.message.Messgae'>

html_msg = msg.get_payload(1)                       #type: <class 'email.message.Message'>

body = html_msg.get_payload(decode=True)            #type: <class 'bytes'> or type: 'int'

html = body.decode()                                #type: <class 'str'>
for line in html:
    if ("Package" in line):
        print("line:", line)

tables = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find_all("table")  #type: <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
data = []
for table in tables:
    for row in table.find_all("tr"):
        data.append([cell.text.strip() for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```

Comment: I tried adding a line `chunks = soup.find_all('p',  {'class' : "MsoNormal"})` before your last `for`-loop, then modified the last `for`-loop as: `for line in chunks:
    if 'Package' in line.text:
        print line.text
        for table in tables:`... remainder of for loop unchanged. I got each line `Package #`, followed by that packages corresponding Fish-Weight values. Might it work for you too? I can post the full code if it's not clear.

Comment: Does `chunks` go after `for table in tables`? You know what, yeah if could post it that'd be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: yes, shouldn't matter where `chunks` goes, but I put it after `tables` and before the `for line in chunks` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='table') # and tag.has_attr('id') and tag['id']=="Table1") 

chunks = soup.find_all('p',  {'class' : "MsoNormal"})

for line in chunks:
    if 'Package' in line.text:
        print line.text
        for table in tables:
            for row in table.find_all("tr"):
                print [cell.text.strip() for cell in row.find_all("td")]
```

output:

```
Package 1:  $ 500.00
[u'Subject: FW: NEFS 11 fish available']
[u'From: Claire Fitz-Gerald']
[u'Date: 6/2/2016 5:55 PM']
[u'gb cod east', u'', u'1']
[u'gb cod west', u'', u'5']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'148']
[u'gb haddock east', u'', u'1']
[u'gb haddock west', u'', u'2']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'12']
[u'white hake', u'', u'4']
[u'pollock', u'', u'162']
[u'redfish', u'', u'25']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'916']
[u'gom winter fl', u'', u'498']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'284']
[u'white hake', u'', u'505']
[u'dab', u'', u'1,293']
[u'pollock', u'', u'812']
[u'redfish', u'', u'1,910']
[u'witch fl', u'', u'352']
[u'cc/gom yellowtail', u'', u'306']
[u'gb cod east', u'', u'', u'5']
[u'gb cod west', u'', u'', u'17']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'', u'5,000']
[u'gom winter fl', u'', u'', u'2,900']
[u'gb haddock east', u'', u'', u'836']
[u'gb haddock west', u'', u'', u'2,118']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'', u'18,000']
[u'white hake', u'', u'', u'8,842']
[u'dab', u'', u'', u'8,650']
[u'pollock', u'', u'', u'78,000']
[u'redfish', u'', u'', u'35,923']
[u'witch fl', u'', u'', u'3,250']
[u'cc/gom yellowtail', u'', u'', u'2,250']
​Package 2: $ 5,225.00
[u'Subject: FW: NEFS 11 fish available']
[u'From: Claire Fitz-Gerald']
[u'Date: 6/2/2016 5:55 PM']
[u'gb cod east', u'', u'1']
[u'gb cod west', u'', u'5']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'148']
[u'gb haddock east', u'', u'1']
[u'gb haddock west', u'', u'2']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'12']
[u'white hake', u'', u'4']
[u'pollock', u'', u'162']
[u'redfish', u'', u'25']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'916']
[u'gom winter fl', u'', u'498']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'284']
[u'white hake', u'', u'505']
[u'dab', u'', u'1,293']
[u'pollock', u'', u'812']
[u'redfish', u'', u'1,910']
[u'witch fl', u'', u'352']
[u'cc/gom yellowtail', u'', u'306']
[u'gb cod east', u'', u'', u'5']
[u'gb cod west', u'', u'', u'17']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'', u'5,000']
[u'gom winter fl', u'', u'', u'2,900']
[u'gb haddock east', u'', u'', u'836']
[u'gb haddock west', u'', u'', u'2,118']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'', u'18,000']
[u'white hake', u'', u'', u'8,842']
[u'dab', u'', u'', u'8,650']
[u'pollock', u'', u'', u'78,000']
[u'redfish', u'', u'', u'35,923']
[u'witch fl', u'', u'', u'3,250']
[u'cc/gom yellowtail', u'', u'', u'2,250']
Package 3:  $ 44,150.00
[u'Subject: FW: NEFS 11 fish available']
[u'From: Claire Fitz-Gerald']
[u'Date: 6/2/2016 5:55 PM']
[u'gb cod east', u'', u'1']
[u'gb cod west', u'', u'5']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'148']
[u'gb haddock east', u'', u'1']
[u'gb haddock west', u'', u'2']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'12']
[u'white hake', u'', u'4']
[u'pollock', u'', u'162']
[u'redfish', u'', u'25']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'916']
[u'gom winter fl', u'', u'498']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'284']
[u'white hake', u'', u'505']
[u'dab', u'', u'1,293']
[u'pollock', u'', u'812']
[u'redfish', u'', u'1,910']
[u'witch fl', u'', u'352']
[u'cc/gom yellowtail', u'', u'306']
[u'gb cod east', u'', u'', u'5']
[u'gb cod west', u'', u'', u'17']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'', u'5,000']
[u'gom winter fl', u'', u'', u'2,900']
[u'gb haddock east', u'', u'', u'836']
[u'gb haddock west', u'', u'', u'2,118']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'', u'18,000']
[u'white hake', u'', u'', u'8,842']
[u'dab', u'', u'', u'8,650']
[u'pollock', u'', u'', u'78,000']
[u'redfish', u'', u'', u'35,923']
[u'witch fl', u'', u'', u'3,250']
[u'cc/gom yellowtail', u'', u'', u'2,250']
Package 4:  $ 43,135.00
[u'Subject: FW: NEFS 11 fish available']
[u'From: Claire Fitz-Gerald']
[u'Date: 6/2/2016 5:55 PM']
[u'gb cod east', u'', u'1']
[u'gb cod west', u'', u'5']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'148']
[u'gb haddock east', u'', u'1']
[u'gb haddock west', u'', u'2']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'12']
[u'white hake', u'', u'4']
[u'pollock', u'', u'162']
[u'redfish', u'', u'25']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'916']
[u'gom winter fl', u'', u'498']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'284']
[u'white hake', u'', u'505']
[u'dab', u'', u'1,293']
[u'pollock', u'', u'812']
[u'redfish', u'', u'1,910']
[u'witch fl', u'', u'352']
[u'cc/gom yellowtail', u'', u'306']
[u'gb cod east', u'', u'', u'5']
[u'gb cod west', u'', u'', u'17']
[u'gom cod', u'', u'', u'5,000']
[u'gom winter fl', u'', u'', u'2,900']
[u'gb haddock east', u'', u'', u'836']
[u'gb haddock west', u'', u'', u'2,118']
[u'gom haddock', u'', u'', u'18,000']
[u'white hake', u'', u'', u'8,842']
[u'dab', u'', u'', u'8,650']
[u'pollock', u'', u'', u'78,000']
[u'redfish', u'', u'', u'35,923']
[u'witch fl', u'', u'', u'3,250']
[u'cc/gom yellowtail', u'', u'', u'2,250']
```

Unfortunately there is some redundant, non-correlated repetition in each iteration with

```
[u'Subject: FW: NEFS 11 fish available']
[u'From: Claire Fitz-Gerald']
[u'Date: 6/2/2016 5:55 PM']
```

which may be circumvented if desired.

Comment: Idk man it's not even coming close to working for me. I suck at HTML stuff and I'm not very familiar with BeautifulSoup. I'll keep trying to make your code work tomorrow though because your printout looks exactly how I'd want it. Eventually I turn the data into a DataFrame so I just want to capture that Package price and append it to its corresponding stuff

Comment: really? hm, I'm sorry. In your code you've got `html = body.decode()` since it's a string you should be able to swap `html_doc` in my code with that `html` variable. I basically copied your `html` file that you pasted into a string and ran my code on it.

Comment: Ok ok so it was that `html_doc` piece that was messing up my code, as usual it was a stupid mistake on my part. Your code worked perfectly. So basically with an HTML document you can't do simple commands like `if 'Package' in line:`, you must do something like use `BeautifulSoup` and find the `p` tags and `MsoNormal` tags, then use commands more similar to `if 'Package' in line.text:`, am I understanding this right?

Comment: Also, this produces each Fish-Weight pair as its own list, with the Price outside all the corresponding lists; so when I go to turn these lists into a DataFrame, as I had before, it sort of fails. This might not be the right place to ask this question, I might have to pose a new SO question, but do you know how to turn all these lists into one single neat DataFrame? And also append the Package Price value to all it's corresponding fish?

Comment: Sorry I haven't answered your questions in your comments yet, I noticed my answer is terribly incorrect (as you noted it repeats all Fish-Weight pairs for each Price, instead of *each* corresponding Fish-Weight pairs for each Price). I've been trying to fix this. Sorry I didn't clarify the 'html_doc' was just the "String" representation of your `html = body.decode()`, and (since the HTML is just a string) you're right, you can just do something like `if 'Package' in line:` and if the object is a BS `tag` type we first need to get the string value from it using `tag.text` then we can search it

Comment: So yes you're understanding it right. As for turning it into a DataFrame will depend on being able to accomplish the last question, if I could figure out how to prepend the Package Price values to their corresponding Fish-Weight prices, then that can be turned into a DataFrame, but not the way I have currently (inaccurately) posed the answer.

Comment: Right right right, that all makes sense. Well, I explored moving that last line (the `cell.text.strip()` line) outside the various `for` loops in an effort to isolate just the `Package` line in order to combine our codes: my original code would capture all the Fish-Weight pairs and yours would capture the Package prices....but then I run into the problem of appending the Price value to the Fish pairs because there's no way for Python to know which Fish pairs I want which specific Prices to go with. This is a very difficult project, I know.